# Understanding and using \& in vim search-and-replace

Tags: regex, vim

I have come across the following specifier for a vim pattern on http://vimregex.com/:

> `\&` --        the next line where the previously used substitute pattern matches

And not quite sure what an example of finding the next line would be. What would be an example of using this in a search-and-replace, and how would it work? I've used `\/` and `\?`  to get the previous/next **search** pattern, but I wasn't quite sure what using the **substitution** pattern would like like, or allow one to do.

Comment: For whoever migrated this here (since I can’t comment on the original), [vi.se] exists...

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an odd one, because elsewhere, Vim doesn't make a distinction between *search patterns* (e.g. from `/search` or `*`) and *substitution patterns* (i.e. the `{pattern}` part in a `:substitute/{pattern}/{text}/{flags}` command); both are stored in the *last search pattern* register ([`:help quote/`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quote%2F)).

My best guess at this distinction in Ex command ranges is that it allows reuse of the substitution pattern in a subsequent part of a range when the start of the range has already used a search:

```
:substitute/bar/xxx/
:/foo/,\&print
```

In this example, `\/` would already have been clobbered by the preceding `/foo/` search, whereas `\&` holds on to the original pattern. However, I would have solved that by inserting the previous pattern via [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R) instead:

```
:/foo/,/<C-R>//print
```